# Como bloquear un input al presionar boton aceptar angular

Tags: angular, typescript

como bloquear o inhabilitar input al presionar boton en angular

```html
<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="Validar" 
     class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart">Aceptar
    </button>

    <input type="string" name="telefono"  id="telefono"  class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: No manejo angular pero si JS, deberías en algún punto darle un listener al evento click y en el callback de ese listener deshabilitar el input

Answer (score 0):

Hola ricardo te dejo la solución a lo que pides.

```js
TS:


public isClicked: boolean = false;

  public bloquear(): void {
    this.isClicked = true;
  }

  public desbloquear(): void {
    this.isClicked = false;
 }
```

```html
HTML:

<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="Validar"
     class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart" (click)="bloquear()">Aceptar
</button>

<input type="string" name="telefono"  id="telefono"  class="form-control" [disabled]="isClicked"/>

<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="Validar"
     class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart"(click)="desbloquear()">Desbloquear
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la propiedad "[disabled]" en el input para habilitarlo/deshabilitarlo y con el evento valida con una funcion que te devuelva true o false para pasarsela a esa propiedad.

```
<input [disabled]="state" ...>
<button (click)="someFunction()" ...>
```

en el archivo .ts agregas esto:

```
state = false;

someFunction() {
  this.state = !this.state;

}
```

Comment: Nomas vienen a que les hagamos la tarea XD

Answer (score 0):

yo creo que la manera mas rápida y sencilla es a través de el condicional *ngIf.

1º Añadiría el condicional *ngIf dependiendo de una variable que comenzase siendo falsa.

2º Añadiría una función que cambiase el valor de este cuando se clickase en el botón

```
component.html:

<button (click)="funcion()"
        type="submit" class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart">
     Aceptar
</button>

<input *ngIf="boton_pulsado"
type="string" name="telefono"  id="telefono"  class="form-control"/>
```

La directiva *ngIf usada en el html, entre otras, permite usar variables declaradas en el archivo .ts

```
component.ts:

const boton_pulsado: boolean = false;

funcion(){
   this.boton_pulsado = !this.boton_pulsado;
}
```

La visibilidad de un elemento que tiene la directiva *ngIf depende de si este condicional es TRUE o FALSE

Comment: Nomas vienen a que les hagamos la tarea XD

Answer (score 0):

Un poco más sencillo podría ser así, ahorras una (o varias) función haciendo una asignación directa

**HTML**

```
<button 
 type="submit" 
 name="add_to_cart" 
 id="Validar" 
 class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart"
 (click)="disabledInput = !disabledInput">
  Aceptar
</button>
 
<input 
type="string" 
name="telefono"  
id="telefono"  
class="form-control" 
[disabled]="disabledInput">
```

**TS**

```
disabledInput: boolean = false;
```